# How to mail merge multiple records to one document

Tags: ms-word

I need to mail merge Access data from multiple records into 1 document.  The document has standard text (form letter in the code below) at the top, followed by fields common to all the records (vendor), followed by multiple rows unique to each record (BC, Account, subaccount, amount), finally followed by more common data (payee) and text (more stuff).

Instead of putting all the record specific data together in the middle of the document, I get the first block of common data, then data from 1 record, the the rest of the common data, then the data from the 2nd record.

My setup in Word is

```
{ if{ mergeseq } ="1" { set var1 "" } { set var1{ mergefield key } }}
{ if { var1 } <>{ var2 } "{ if { mergeseq } <>"1" "}
Form letter
{ MERGEFIELD "Vendor_" }
" ""}
{ MERGEFIELD "BC" } { MERGEFIELD "Account" } { MERGEFIELD "SubAccount" }
{ MERGEFIELD "Amount" }
{ if { var1 } <>{ var2 } "{ if { mergeseq } <>"1" "}
more stuff
{ MERGEFIELD payee}
" ""}
{ set var2 { mergefield key }}
```

I'm using Office 2010.

Comment: I suggest you create a VIEW in ACCESS (or a temporary table), merge your data there, then have Word pull that data.  It's much easier than trying to force MailMerge to do it.  If you get into a real jam, you can actually write SQL code to do the merge, rather than using the MailMerge Wizard.

Comment: I thought of doing that - but it seemed cumbersome in Access to combine multiple records into one.  I'm not sure what the maximum number of records per key is so I cannot just create a simple query to  merge everything, and there is more than 1 field that I need for the mail merge so I cannot use a crosstab query.

Comment: I did the query in Access for a limited number of records, with a check to ensure I stay within the programmed limit.  It works, but is not a general solution.  If I find more records than I planned on, I will need to maintain the query and the mail merge template to accommodate more.  I'd still like a general fix that isn't limited to a maximum record count on each page.